# Cannot login to SourceTree

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

My company has a Bitbucket account with Atlassian. I've downloaded the latest update to Sourcetree; when I try and login my credentials are not accepted.

[image: Sourcetree login page]

The same happens if I access this page through my web browser here: https://id.atlassian.com/login?application=mac&continue=https://my.atlassian.com

However if I try to login to https://company.atlassian.net/login? it works fine.

Is there some convention I have to use to tell Atlassian my company name as part of my login user ID (ie username@company)?

Sourcetree won't let me do anything without getting past this screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try quitting the SourceTree app and re-launching.

I had a similar problem. My `id.atlassian.com` credentials worked online but repeatedly failed in SourceTree. It worked for me after a relaunch.

Atlassian recommends sticking with the older version at the moment: https://twitter.com/sourcetree/status/699624992003244033

**Update**
On Feb 22, Atlassian [apologized](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2016/02/22/sourcetree-update-atlassian-account-git-lfs-support-ui-refresh-and-more/) and released SourceTree 2.2.2. However, some folks are still tweeting issues with the initial login on the [release announcement](https://twitter.com/sourcetree/status/701865840673693696).

Comment: Thanks. That link actually had the solution - install version 2.2 (I was on 1.7). Works fine now

Comment: Glad it worked for you! For folks having issues with 2.2, download 2.1 at http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/SourceTree_2.1.dmg

Comment: Every time I reinstall windows I can't figure out why soucetree won't accept my password. I end up here everytime. Thanks

Comment: On Feb 10th 2017, The 1.9 version install on windows also hung this step. With a right-click popup menu and select to see the bottom 'properties', the login window flashed and login done :-| Might this help others.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all other authentications ids in Authentication section in sourcetree other than git hub.

Then click Add or either go to Hosted repositories(to quickly check if it was successful) and click on edit accounts.

In credentials select OAuth and select refresh token. You will be redirected to your logged in bitbucket website and there click on Grant access.

Now goto your fresh account in Authentication section in sourcetree and select Set as Default.

Done. Now you should see all your repositories in hosted repositories. It shows login error if it is not successful

Answer (score 0):

I ran the app from Downloads folder and had this issue.
**moving to Applications folder fixed it in my case.**

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your git is up to date.

If updating git doesn't do the trick and if you are using Windows you can install/update
https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases

From the project's homepage at github:

> As of 22 Feb 2018, GitHub has disabled support for weak encryption
>   which means many users will suddenly find themselves unable to
>   authenticate using a Git for Windows which (impacts versions older
>   than v2.16.0). DO NOT PANIC, there's a fix. Update Git for Windows to
>   the latest (or at least v2.16.0).